# Can you see through me? Then guess my name!

Tags: knowledge, visual, steganography

This is yet another guess-my-character puzzle. Here you are:

[image: Puzzle image]

My name relies on two things:

1. The **technique** used to find the hidden text in the image.
2. The **meaning** of the text inside the image.

---

**HINT 1**

> The technique used to **create** the image differs from the technique used to **see** the image. It's the way you see it that matters.

**HINT 2**

> The text in the image and the technique used to see the image should be considered independently. There's no connection between them. Also, the technique and the meaning relate, respectively, to the first and second words in the answer.

**HINT 3**

> My name has two words that can be found in any common English dictionary.

**HINT 4**

> I went to Los Angeles and spent some time there.

**HINT 5**

> I'm a pretender.

**HINT 6**

> According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autostereogram), there are only two ways to see an stereogram:
>
>  [image: How to see and stereogram.]

**HINT 7**

> I have bad posture and love for sweets.

**HINT 8**

> He had the idea right, he just didn't connect the dots yet:
>
>  *"When I first looked at the stereogram, I just crossed my eyes and then stared "behind" the picture."* (@Hugh)
>
>   **Notice:** Aaaaaaand this is where I stop giving hints. One more hint and I'll be answering the puzzle.

**HINT 9**

> Ok, last hint: I'm a serial killer, but I'm not part of the main story.

---

**Off-topic:**

What's your opinion on this puzzle? Is it good? Is it bad? I'd like to hear from you!
<sub>You can answer in a comment or in the end of you answer.</sub>

Comment: Please tell us!

Answer (score 5):

**Partial Answer**

> The first step is to solve the "[magic eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Eye) / [autostereogram puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autostereogram)". By crossing your eyes and moving the picture back and forth, an image should float up.
>
>  [image: autosterogram]
>
>  Not sure what to do after that, though. I can't really think of a way to describe the "technique" used to "see" an autostereogram, nor do I understand what the solved autostereogram is referring to. If I assume that "I" refers to the autostereogram itself, there are still many dates involved in the history and creation of autostereograms.

Comment: Birthday Stripogram?

Comment: @Hugh You already "decryptded" the image (by using some software), but I'm guessing that you still can't see it for yourself. There's an specific way to see it. Once you realize how it's done, then you'll be able to describe it in the proper way. The definition in the second phrase of your partial answer is too generic to be useful.

Comment: @PedroCorso When I first looked at the stereogram, I just crossed my eyes and then stared "behind" the picture. Then the words started to float up, but couldn't make out the letters so I used an online tool. I'll take another look and see if I can make something different out of it.

Comment: You're already on the right track! ;)

Comment: Do the technique and the meaning relate, respectively, to the first and second words in the answer?

Comment: @tmpearce Yes. I'll add that as a complement to the 2nd hint for clarity.

Answer (score 4):

You're thinking of

> **Beyond Birthday** from Death Note Another Note: The Los Angeles BB Murder Cases

His name consists of the words

> Beyond - as you see beyond the picture to decode it and
> Birthday - as in, the day you were born.

Both of the words are very common and can reasonably be found in any English dictionary.

Additional hints:

Hint 4:

> the plot of the story occurs in LA

Hint 5:

> he is indeed a master of disguise, in fact we never find out his true face.

Hint 7:

> while unknown whether these are his actual character traits or part of the game, he is noted as really liking strawberry jam and for some reason walks on all fours from time to time.